# Best way to deal with environment-sourced constants when rspec testing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I have a model that has a constant that looks like:

```ruby
  SOURCE_QUOTA = {
    'free' => (ENV['FREE_SOURCE_QUOTA'] || '5').to_i,
    'premium' => (ENV['PREMIUM_SOURCE_QUOTA'] || '100').to_i
  }.freeze
```

RuboCop suggests "Style/MutableConstant" and that the freeze should be there.

However, during testing, I want to use slightly different values. Now, I could actually modify the ENV of the bash session where I launch rspec. Sure. But modifying it in the code makes life easier. For example:

```ruby
  describe "a thing" do
    it "does stuff" do
      ENV['FREE_SOURCE_QUOTA'] = '2'
      DataSource::SOURCE_QUOTA["free"] = ENV['FREE_SOURCE_QUOTA'].to_i
      # test code
```

The above works when the constant isn't frozen. I assume that's because, when frozen, the Model is loaded during the loading of the Rails environment and then this value cannot be muted (it's frozen!).

What would be the best thing to do here?

- stick with frozen constant and be sure to set desired env before the rspec run?
- don't freeze the constant and keep the above test
- do something else that involves unfreezing/refreezing/reloading model?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I would think about using a class method instead of a constant, like this:

```
# in your model
def self.source_quota
  {
    'free' => (ENV['FREE_SOURCE_QUOTA'] || '5').to_i,
    'premium' => (ENV['PREMIUM_SOURCE_QUOTA'] || '100').to_i
  }
end
```

and then mock that method in your tests like this:

```
allow(DataSource).to receive(source_quota)and_return('free' => 2)
```

Comment: I like this idea. It would require other code changes, but it's definitely appealing!

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use RSpec's [`stub_const`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/mutating-constants) feature. This allows you to stub the constant value to whatever you want in your example.

Your test code might look something like

```
describe 'a thing' do
  before { stub_const('DataSource::SOURCE_QUOTA', {'free' => 2}) } 
  it 'does stuff' do
    expect(DataSource::SOURCE_QUOTA["free"]).to eq 2
    # test code
```